# Why does the Electron browser reload after running each spec when using cypress run?

Tags: electron, cypress

How do I ensure that all the spec files run without the browser reloading?

Answer (score 0):

If by "spec" you mean each individual `it`:

If you set a `baseUrl` in your `cypress.json` and use relative URLs in `cy.visit()` (like `cy.visit('/home')`), Cypress shouldn't reload between specs.